# WPF stackpanel scrolling issues

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollviewer, stackpanel

i have this in my window and i'll be adding items programmatically to these stacks. problem is i can't scroll through my stuff. i have tried everything that i can find online but i couldn't.

```
<Border x:Name="Border_Output" Width="463" Height="463" CornerRadius="30" 
                                    BorderThickness="0" Background="White">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel x:Name="Restaurant_SearchOutputStack"/>
        <StackPanel x:Name="Item_SearchOutputStack"/>
        <StackPanel x:Name="Order_OutputStack"/>
        <StackPanel x:Name="Menu_OutputStack"/>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

Comment: What do you mean by _i have tried everything_? Have you tried [`ScrollViewer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: What is the size of your parent window?

Comment: The fact that you have given names to your stackpanels suggest that you are indeed adding to them *in code*. Please consider using MVVM and Data Binding to do this, it's the preferred way and ignoring it will make it a lot harder to get productive with WPF. A grid is not meant to be scrolled, because it's not an items control. Use a container like a listview to get scrolling.

Comment: well ill learn MVVM later i just have to finish this in any way due to some deadlines. and yes i have tried list views scrollviewers but each had some error of sometimes not scrolling sometimes not showing the scroll bar..

Answer (score 3):

If you have a stackpanel, it is assigned the size of it's items, so the scrollerbar won't appear.

From [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/659066/ListBox-and-Panels-in-WPF):

> As you can see, having a ListBox in a StackPanel causes the
>   ScrollViewer to disappear, since the StackPanel gives its children the
>   entire size they need, rendering the collection without the
>   ScrollViewer.

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer.. it was to have it this way instead.

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                        <Grid>
                            <StackPanel x:Name="Restaurant_SearchOutputStack"/>
                            <StackPanel x:Name="Item_SearchOutputStack"/>
                            <StackPanel x:Name="Order_OutputStack"/>
                            <StackPanel x:Name="Menu_OutputStack"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ScrollViewer>
```

and because when i use one stack i collapse the others what i want happens correctly. thanks anyways guys.